# Wikidata structure: how to get Start Times when they are under Point in Time

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I ran queries to gain dates of instances of an incident, and used Point in Time (P585).
[Link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fincident%20%3Flabel%20%3Ftime%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fincident%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ625994.%0A%20%20%3Fincident%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel.%0A%20%20%3Fincident%20wdt%3AP585%20%3Ftime.%0A%20%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%7D)

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ?incident ?label ?time WHERE {
   ?incident wdt:P31 wd:Q625994.
   ?incident rdfs:label ?label.
   ?incident wdt:P585 ?time.
   FILTER((LANG(?label)) = "en")
   }
```

However, result cases such as re:publica would only give me year information in the form of January 1, 2007 ~ 2016.  (they occurred in April or May, and I would like more specific info like that)

Then I saw [re:publica](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2134501) also has Start Dates & End Dates under Point in Time, per year. Therefore, I tried changing wdt:585 into wdt:580 (Start Dates), however, then I would not get re:publica in my results because apparently it is not considered to have 'start dates' if I query this way (because it is under Point in Time).

How do I get start time when Start Time is under Point in Time? Or, in general, how do I get certain info I want when it's under some other properties?

Comment: Working on it: for anyone with similar questions, [this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/WIKIDATA_Qualifiers,_References_and_Ranks) is helpful.

Comment: yes, with the examples it's pretty simple. In addition, understanding the data model of Wikidata can be achieved by reading [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/DataModel/Primer)